# How to indicate a tempo change during a repetition?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, tempo, repeats

I have a quick question: What's the notation used to indicate that a certain part of a piece is supposed to be played at a higher/lower tempo but **only** during a repetition. For instance, if I have a D.C. al Fine at the end of my piece, and I wanted to play the entire piece 40BPM higher than the original tempo on the **second** run, how could I write it?

Comment: Are you perchance the Super Mario Bros sound designer?

Comment: xD No, actually no ^^

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use text. I would put this information with the D.C. (or D.S.) marking and with the original tempo marking. But I would put it inside a bracket.

So for instance, at the beginning:

"Allegro (faster on D.C.)" or "Allegro (faster 2nd time)"

and

"D.C. al Coda (faster 2nd time)"

You could even write the actual change of tempo. For instance: "Allegro (Presto on D.C.)" or even put the different metronome markings in a similar fashion.

For these kind of distinctions, you can't beat just using text to explain what you want.

Comment: If only computer programming languages had such flexibility!  Here we have it;  don't shy away from using it.